# Input/output error when updating LibreOffice

Tags: updates, libreoffice

I am having problems installing the `libreoffice-help-en-us` update. Details gives me this:

```
dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed to read on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy: Input/output error
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal bzip2 read error: 'UNEXPECTED_EOF'
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run these commands

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And try installing `libreoffice-help-en-us` again .